# First click on commandButton doesn't redirect to another page

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

1. When I enter valid value (only digits) to *inputText* and click *commandButton* then I'am redirected to *response.xhtml*.
2. When I enter invalid value, click on page background, then change event is triggered, message is displayed.
   Now when I enter valid value and click commandButton, **message hides, but I am not redirected**.
   When I click second time I am redirected.

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:inputText id="value" value="#{bean.value}">
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="\d+"/>
                    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="@this valueMessage"/>
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="valueMessage" for="value"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="OK" action="response"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

response.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Value is <h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean.java

```
package app;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused by the hiding message, which in turn causes the command button to move up before its own click event finishes, and thus not sitting below the mouse pointer anymore when the mouse button is released and about to trigger the form submit. If you move the message component to below the command button component like so,

```
<h:commandButton value="OK" action="response"/>
<h:message id="valueMessage" for="value"/>
```

... then the command button will stay at the same place in the UI when the message hides, and thus its click event will be successfully received and trigger the form submit.

This is just an UI design problem, not a technical problem. You need to try to make sure that the button doesn't move away before its click event finishes.

One way is to make the form 2-column wide so that the message is shown next to the input field instead of below it, hereby not occupying more horizontal space:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
```

An alternative is to delay the ajax request with [`<f:ajax delay>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html) attribute (only available since JSF 2.2). I tested with a few values and 100~200ms seems acceptable to cover the time span of an average click (the time from the mouse button press until the mouse button is actually released). This way the ajax request is actually not fired when the submit button is clicked, hereby avoiding the shift of the button (and "unnecessary" validation).

```
<f:ajax render="@this valueMessage" delay="150" />
```

*(note that `event="change"` and `execute="@this"` are the default values already, they are already for clarity omitted in above example; technically `render="@this"` is also strange, but I just kept it in, for the case you actually want to redisplay a changed value after some conversion step)*

Comment: "... the mouse pointer anymore when the mouse button is released and about to trigger the form submit", is that means the form submit happen only once the mouse button is released and that the mouse pointer should be on the button between the click and release? I mean if for example (In context) I click in a commandbutton and I release the mouse out side of it the form will not be submited?

Comment: @Tarik: depends on whether drag'n'drop has been implemented on the dragged button and the area where you drop it. But by default, the form indeed won't be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do it like this in your `index.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid>
       <h:inputText  id="value" value="#{bean.value}">
           <f:validateRegex pattern="\d+" />
       </h:inputText>
       <h:message id="valueMessage" for="value"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="OK"  action="response" >
          <f:ajax  execute="value" render="value valueMessage"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

and btw in your code the first click is for `change` event not for the button so if you try to click anywhere in the page except the button it will make the validation to disappear and the button will redirect you from first hit.